# Destination server missing when exporting tables through SQL import export wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-import-wizard

I have been trying to export some of my tables into a remote database server but its not appearing in the list. I have Win 10 with SQL 2014. I am running another OS (Windows server R2) through hyper V-manager. What I am trying to do is to export my tables from Windows R2 to my Win 10 through SQL import export wizard. But my Win 10 SQL server is not appearing in the list of servers when exporting through wizard. I have enabled my TCP/IP of SQL server but still same issue.

Comment: You can just enter IP of your Win 10 computer into the server name field

Comment: I tried with this 192.168.100.28\SQLEXPRESS but still same issue . The ping response to the ip is successful too